# Android (JAVA) — object serialization error

Tags: java, android, serialization

When I try serialize object - application crashes with error:

```
06-02 17:44:38.809  19898-19898/com.ibank.for_business E/serializeObject﹕ error
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.json.JSONObject
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
        etc...
```

Serializable object:

```
public class HistoryItem implements Serializable {

    public static final int STATE_INCOMING = 1;
    public static final int STATE_OUTGOING = 0;
    public static final int STATE_UNKNOWN = -1;

    private String status;
    private String date = UDate.today(UDate.FORMAT_DMY);
    private String time;
    private String number;
    private String amount;
    private String description;
    private String incoming;
    private int isIncoming;
    private String account;
    private String name;

    public static HistoryItem fromJSON(final JSONObject json) {
        return new HistoryItem() {{
            setStatus(optString("status", json));
            setDate(optString("date", json));
            setTime(optString("time", json));
            setNumber(optString("number", json));
            setAmount(optString("amount", json));
            setDescription(optString("description", json));
            setIncoming(optString("incoming", json));
            setAccount(optString("account", json));
            setName(optString("name", json));
        }};
    }

    // ... Getters and setters

}
```

I understand that the application swears serialization JSONObject but as far as I know, only serialized class field.

Possible to solve this problem leaving a method fromJSON?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: error is might be throw at where you try to getting this object...
at there you must have to get this object with `getSerializeble` Like some thing type of method plz check.

Comment: did you tyr with the `Parselable` if not then try it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `fromJSON` method, you are using the double-brace initialization pattern: `{{ ... }}`. What you are actually doing there is creating an anonymous subclass of `HistoryItem` with an instance initializer block.

The anonymous subclass has an invisible, implicit reference to the argument of the `fromJSON` method. When you try to serialize this object, you'll get a `NotSerializableException` because the object that the invisible reference refers to, a `JSONObject`, is not serializable.

Remove the use of the double-brace initialization pattern and just create a regular instance of `HistoryItem` instead of an anonymous subclass:

```
public static HistoryItem fromJSON(final JSONObject json) {
    HistoryItem item = new HistoryItem();

    item.setStatus(optString("status", json));
    item.setDate(optString("date", json));
    item.setTime(optString("time", json));
    item.setNumber(optString("number", json));
    item.setAmount(optString("amount", json));
    item.setDescription(optString("description", json));
    item.setIncoming(optString("incoming", json));
    item.setAccount(optString("account", json));
    item.setName(optString("name", json));

    return item;
}
```